# Showing that the complements of a subspace have the same dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $U$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ with complement subspace given by $W_1$. I am trying to show that, if $W_2$ is another complement subspace of $U$, then $\dim(W_1) = \dim(W_2)$. Initially I tried comparing basis elements. That is, let a basis of $W_1$ be $\{w_1,w_2,w_3,\ldots, w_n\}$ and a basis for $W_2$ be $\{\hat{w}_1, \hat{w}_2, \ldots, \hat{w}_m\}$. Without loss of generality, take $m > n$. Any $\hat{w}_i \in W_2$ can be represented uniquely as $\hat{w}_i = u + w_i$ for $u \in U$ and $w_i \in W_1$, as $U + W_1 = V$. I'm not sure if this is the correct approach, as I don't see how this can eventually yield a direct proof or at the very least a proof by contradiction.

Any hints are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Show that, if subspaces $U$ and $W$ are complementary in $V$, with bases $B_1$ and $B_2$ respectively, then $B_1 \cup B_2$ is a basis for $V$. Such a union is necessarily disjoint, so what does this say about the dimension of $W$ in terms of $U$ and $V$?

Comment: $\dim(W) = \dim(V) - \dim(U)$?

Comment: @DerekAdams That's right. So, show the result about unioning bases, and you're done. Let me know if you need me to expand the hint to a full answer.